# Remove a decimal and concat zero at a specific position using PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I have a column named `invoice_number` varchar(255) in the `invoices` table.

Here is some sample data:

20220010000000010
20220010000000011
20220010000000012

An `invoice_number` can have up to 17 digits. Here is the format in which it is generated:

Year(4 digits) + Number of invoice (3 digits) + profile number (10 digits)

At the moment, I have some data in this column as follows:

202200100000022.1
202200100000022.2
202200100000022.3

I would like to delete the decimal point which is the 2nd to the last digit and then add a zero on the 8th position (after 001 according to the sample data above) to handle all of these undesired invoice numbers.

Expected Output:

20220010000000221
20220010000000222
20220010000000223

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A safe way to do it is using `REGEXP_REPLACE`.

> ```
> select invoice_number
> , regexp_replace(invoice_number, '^([0-9]{4})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{8})[.]([0-9]+)$', '\1\20\3\4') as new_invoice_number
> from (values
>   ('202200100000022.1')
> , ('202200100000022.2') 
> , ('202200100000022.3') 
> ) q(invoice_number)
> where invoice_number like '%.%';
> ```

> | invoice_number | new_invoice_number |
> | --- | --- |
> | 202200100000022.1 | 20220010000000221 |
> | 202200100000022.2 | 20220010000000222 |
> | 202200100000022.3 | 20220010000000223 |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=a2ab0c168b079fc173a218dad8643702)*

Comment: I just want to remove the decimal and not the number after it.

Comment: Okay, see updated solution.

Comment: I have 1200+ rows in this column that have this decimal problem. What would be the best way to use your query for updating all of these at once?
If you want I can also share the schema of the table.

Comment: something like `update your_table set invoice_number =regexp_replace(invoice_number::varchar, '^([0-9]{4})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{8})[.]([0-9]+)$', '\1\20\3\4')::numeric
where invoice_number != floor(invoice_number)`

Comment: Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  function floor(character varying) does not exist
LINE 2: ...$', '\1\20\3\4')::numeric where invoice_number != floor(invo...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Oh lol, well I had made an assumption that it was a numeric field. Turns out's a varchar.  change the `WHERE` clause to `where invoice_number like '%.%'`  And the type cast `::numeric` won't be needed.

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot. I also added the information to my question that the column is a varchar(255).

Comment: Btw, I said it's safe because this method won't change strings that don't fit the pattern.